# Use Lambda expression to get value from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

Despite a lot of searching, I can't get the correct Lambda expression the get the info I want from the DB. My problem is this:

An Action method in the controller gets an id value as an in parameter. With the id, I want to get the Name in the Products class that match the id with the Products CategoriesID. I have started, but I don't know how to finish it. Can I get some help with this? I guess I'm doing wrong here?

```
ViewBag.Categori = db.Products.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(??))
```

Comment: so, you need the name of the product which matches the id parameter?

Comment: @Zippy Yes that is what I want!

Comment: Why does people bother to downvote!?

Comment: @front-back, I don't know either, but it is annoying b/c there is no explanation as to why they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the name of the product that matches a specific `id` you write following `LINQ` query

```
db.Products.Where(x => x.Id == desiredId)
           .Select(x => x.Name)
           .SingleOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understood the question right, you don't need to filter by the `name` property but by the `id` one.

Something like:

```
    var product = db.Products.Where(x => x.CategoriesID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if(product != null)
    {
    ViewBag.Categori = product.Name;
    }
```

The `FirstOrDefault` will return only the first match or null if there's no product with the specified Id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in the View I get this: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Products_A0A267...... instead of the name!?

Comment: My bad, the `FirstOrDefault` should've been before the select, as Julia stated in her answer.

Comment: Now I get a red line below the Select !?

Comment: Thanks, but with the latest option I get a Null Reference error !!

Comment: That's because there's no product with that id and the FirstOrDefault returns null. Try with an Id which you know it's right

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it worked with Michael Maireggers code.

Answer (score 1):

As you are returning one result you can use FirstOrDefault.

```
ViewBag.Categori = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Name
```

In the code above i am assuming your product has a key field of Id and the parameter name passed in is id.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewBag.Categori = db.Products.Where(x => x.CategoriesID == id).FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   ViewBag.Categori = DB.Context.Products.Where(w => w.ProductTypeId == id).Select(s => new
        {
            Name = s.ProductName
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```